# Connecting spring boot application with IBM MQ Server using SSL certificate

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, ibm-mq, sslcontext

I've an application written in Java, spring boot. Details about that is mentioned below:

1. Application is deployed on Openshift Container
2. Application have to connect to IBM MQ Hub as for messaging, which is a remote server
3. To communicate with MQ server, I'll have to enable a secure connection between application and server
4. To implement secure connection between application and MQ server, we are using certificate based authentication.
5. Certificate is a Venafi certificate and it is stored in container at different location
6. Certificate password is encrypted and key to decrypt that is given to us
7. Now, we have to write a code to enable secure connection between my application and MQ server by fetching certificate first and followed by decrypting it and then establishing secure connection.

I've implemented using URL to fetch the certificate path then decrypting then creating a trustStoreManager.

Finally, I've initialised it using SSLContext.init method.

But it seems like this is not proper implementation. Can anyone please guide me?

TIA!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you using `mq-jms-spring-boot-starter` as a dependency?